# How to do a dynamic site menu?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let me explain what I'm trying to do, from the very basics

So, my app has a top menu bar

This is, for a various host of reasons, defined externally, and the structure is available via my rest API:

```
App.Menu = DS.Model.extend({
  parent: DS.belongsTo("App.Menu"),
  children: DS.hasMany("App.Menu"),
  link: DS.attr("string"),
  route: DS.attr("string"),
  title: DS.attr("string")})
```

I need *something*, to run, when the app starts up, App.Menu.find(), and then take that collection, and iterate over it in a template, which is then included in the application template.

Controller didn't work

View didn't work, I can't seem to really figure out collectionviews

Even embedding it right in the application template isn't working as there's no collection at that point

Actually, to make it even MORE interesting, each menu item has many children
and ideally will call a subtemplate for each child, recursively

Answer (score 0):

When your app loads, it goes to the root state from your router. This is where you want to start looking.

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/

You can setup a controller and retrieve your menu.